# Java Linked HashMap

Tags: java

I have this simple code in which an arraylist will be passed to a hash map to remove the duplicate records and add all the records back to the same araylist:

```
ArrayList<String> masterRecords = new ArrayList<String>();

String perLine;
// Read file per line
while ((perLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    masterRecords.add(perLine);
}

br.close();

// Remove duplicates using hash map
HashSet<String> uniqueRecords = new HashSet<String>();
uniqueRecords.addAll(masterRecords);
masterRecords.clear();
masterRecords.addAll(uniqueRecords);
```

My data is a csv record, something like:

```
/EON_2,-,EON_2,9R25M_ROADM_001,OCH-L-1-1-1-68,OPT-F,PMTypeOptical,NEND,TDTC,15-MIN,Dec 08 2014  - 10:30:00 PM MYT,NA,NA
```

The problem is all records are not in the same order and I want to preserve how they were sorted before, I read that using linked hash map can do the same (remove uplicates) and at the same time preserve the order of the records. I can't seem to find a good example on how to do it. Anyone can point me to one or have a basic example on how to do it? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `HashSet` is not a `HashMap`. And, you could use a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) like

```
Set<String> uniqueRecords = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

From the linked Javadoc,

> This implementation differs from `HashSet` in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (*insertion-order*).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just using a HashSet of strings, just substitute a LinkedHashSet for the HashSet. It supports the same behavior with order-preserving behavior. This is clearly spelled out in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with
>   predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet
>   in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its
>   entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the
>   order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order).
>   Note that insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted
>   into the set.